# What navigation strategy to choose for iOS project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 4 screens in a project. I know two ways to move from one view to other:

1. `UINavigationController`
2. One `UIViewController` and add subviews to that `UIViewController`.

But, In all screens bottom bar is same. Bottom bar is having some buttons.

So, In my point of view, adding subView to one `UIViewController` is better way.

But I don't know which is best method and standard way for developers?

Comment: You should learn about UIViewController containment.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I already learn but I am asking which is best way to do?

Comment: If you had learned about containment you wouldn't ask.

Comment: @iOS: You forgot to learn about `UITabBarController`. You should read about it to more clear your view. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontroller_class/index.html

Comment: As per my requirements tabbar controller is not needed. Thanks

Comment: @iOS Still, you have to show/hide these 4 screens, if you add as a subview in view controller. You can use `UIPageControl` if it is full fill your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Kampai. Definitely I will try with your suggestion also. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on the way that you expect the users to navigate from one screen to the other:

- **If end-users should be able to get from any screen to any other screen, use tab bar controller** - `UITabBarController` will hold the other four views, and present a tab bar at the bottom. If you do not want the tab bar, you can hide it.
- **If end-users on each view have two choices of view controllers to go to, next and prior, use a page view controller** - This is more appropriate in situations when the navigation is limited to next/previous page.
- **If end-users need to be able to go back to the previous screen, use navigation controller** - `UINavigationController` keeps track of the views that you visited, and provides navigation to go back.

Comment: many Thanks for edit my question and answering my question. Actually my project UI does not use tabbar and page view controller. Thats why I asked which is the best. Once again thanks.

Comment: @iOS - `UITabBarController` is your answer.